# Worklight Studio fixpack installs twice?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I installed a recent iFix for Worklight Studio.

After the install, when I view About Eclipse->Installation Details, I see two versions of Worklight listed ... the new one (6.1.0.01-20140922-2007), and the old (6.1.0.01-20140427-1450).

Does this indicate a problem? If so, how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

That's indeed odd. It might indicate a problem, not sure.

To be on the safe side, easiest would be to use a fresh Eclipse instance with a new workspace and install the latest iFix version and import your existing projects (export them first if you do not already have a backup in some source control).